# Droppings of mystery: What are they

Tags: species-identification

I have noticed the droppings below, quite visible on snow, next to an inner-town building situated next to [this place in Luxembourg, central Europe](https://www.google.com/maps/place/49%C2%B036'49.6%22N+6%C2%B007'39.9%22E/@49.6137945,6.1261944,674m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0). There are quite a few, but I have not noticed them anywhere else. What animal creates these and why do they have this red color which stains the surrounding snow? Is it a cat being fed colored food?

Local wildlife is mostly city pigeons (with digestive tracts of steel), huge flocks of crows (inhabiting parks and occupying the construction cranes at nightfall), maybe a few stray foxes and rabbits. House dogs and cats of course although these don't run around unattended.

[image]

Comment: How big are they? Is the snow melting? (Otherwise it looks like whatever left it did it without leaving tracks.)

Comment: @picapica As big as the the half the pinky. The snow is not melting in this picture, temperature about -4°C. The picture shows the border of a decorative plant-holding trough, rather overgrown, so it's likely there are mice living in there and probably cats doing regular inspections.